# Create records idemponently from the last time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to fetch transaction data from a third party API, and save the records periodically (once a month). Here is an example:

```
class BalanceTransaction::Update
  include Service

  attr_reader :offset, :transactions

  def initialize(offset)
    @offset = offset
    @transactions = fetch_transactions
  end

  def call
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      transactions.auto_paging_each do |txn|
        type = txn[:type]
        source = txn[:source]
        case type
          when 'charge', 'adjustment'
            invoice = find_invoice(source)
            ac_id = invoice.account.id
            update_attrs(id: invoice.id, account_id: ac_id, type:'invoice', attrs: txn)
          when 'refund'
            refund = find_refund(source)
            ac_id = refund.invoice.account.id
            update_attrs(id: refund.id, account_id: ac_id, type:'refund', attrs: txn)
        end
      end
    end
    true
  end

  private

  def find_invoice(source)
    Invoice.find_by!(stripe_charge_id: source)
  end

  def find_refund(source)
    Refund.find_by!(stripe_refund_id: source)
  end

  def update_attrs(id:, account_id:, type:, attrs:)
    BalanceTransaction.create(
      account_id: account_id,
      stripe_transaction_id: attrs[:id],
      gross_amount: attrs[:amount],
      net_amount: attrs[:net],
      fee_amount: attrs[:fee],
      currency: attrs[:currency],
      transactionable_id: id,
      transactionable_type: type)
  end

  def fetch_transactions
    external_card_balance.all(limit: offset)
  rescue *EXTERNAL_CARD_ERRORS => e
    ExternalCardErrorHandler.new(e).handle
  end

  def external_card_balance
    Stripe::BalanceTransaction
  end
end
```

I wonder how to bulk insert idempotently from the last time. Should I check `created_at` and delete them if I find data created after the offset? Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Does the transaction have unique id's or any field that could be made unique? Maybe you could use `validates_uniqueness_of` to avoid saving transactions you already fetched.

Comment: You mean the third party API? If it is, there is! Thanks for the advice! `stripe_transaction_id` is unique.

Comment: This way you don't need to worry about saving the same transaction twice :D